# How to change the text color?

Tags: css

[image: css]

Don't have much experience with css, but how do I override the settings for that highlighted via div class p span? I need to override the color to #ffffff

[Update] thank you for your answers, you all have helped to solve this, have been stuck whole day on this and could not solve it or find the specific tutorial or sample.

Sorry if my question is not very well-formed and very specific without providing much context. And sorry again, if I was not able to find the right answer on google, as CSS looks a bit like voodoo coming from Swift world. I know what I wanted to achieve but I could not find the right way to do it. Thank you all for teaching me something new and useful today.

Comment: Not sure what is stopping you from doing it as I can already see the inline `color` attribute which you can edit and set to white (#fff or #ffffff). Can you please provide some sample code to reproduce the situation that you are facing?

Comment: Add code instead of images.

Comment: If you can't change the inline styles, the only way to override it somewhere else is to use `!important` after the declaration (e.g. `color: #fff!important;`)
Read about [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: @MoaazBhnas https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception also states that "Using !important, however, is bad practice and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in your stylesheets." So it would be good if we find what's stopping OP from changing the inline style.

Comment: OP, the reason you're being downvoted is because this question is not very well-formed for this site. You're asking a very specific question without providing much context, and for the most part the solution seems like it could probably be found by a simple Google search. A summary of what you've tried is usually quite helpful in working to find a better solution for you.

Comment: You need to post code that gives an example of your problem.  Please read **[ask]** and then create a **[mcve]**  With your rep you should know better than to post a question that is this poor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the selector `.woocommerce-product-details__short-description`, you'll select the `div` element that contains the `p` element that contains the `span` you want to style. So to select the span, you could do: `.woocommerce-product-details__short-description > p > span`. This risks selecting more elements than you really want to select - it will select all `span`s that are children of `p`s that are children of elements with the class.

If you wanted to just select this specific element, you'd have to be more specific. Without seeing the rest of the code, it's hard to say exactly what makes this element unique. One consideration is the unique id of the parent product element: `product-45590`. So to make your selector very specific, you might do `#product-45590 .woocommerce-product-details__short-description > p > span`. Note the space vs the `>` symbol. The `>` signifies a direct descendant, like a child to a parent, while the space signifies any descendant, like a grandchild to a grandparent or a child to a parent.

For the actual color-changing once the selector is right, you can just do `color: #ffffff`. However, because of CSS selector specificity, you cannot just override the color on an element that has the color defined with an inline style. So you also have to add `!important` to the rule. Note that this is typically not preferred practice because it means that future developers will have a very hard time overriding your style, but sometimes it's necessary.

Putting it all together:

```css
.woocommerce-product-details__short-description > p > span {
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Comment: Was looking for a way to do this, but could not find the right sample or tutorial. Thank you very much for such a brief explanation. Definitely learned something new  and useful today :)

Answer (score 2):

use below code with important

```
.woocommerce-product-details__short-description > p > span{
   color: #fff!important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you could just edit the `color: #3333` to `color: #fff`

Answer (score 1):

Inline styling in html takes priority, so you will have to change that to your desired colour or use !important after the colour in css.